# How to iterate through a dictionary of tuples?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, dictionary, tuples

I have the following tuples of `month,day` stored in the dictionary `seasons`:

```
seasons = {
    'S1': (
        ((1, 10),(5, 31))
    ),
    'S2': (
        ((9, 1),(1, 9))
    ),
    'S3': (
        ((6, 1),(9, 30))
    )
}
```

I want to check in which date interval a datetime `dt` is located and assign the name `S1`, `S2` or `S3`, accordingly.

I tried to do it this way, but `start` and `end` seem to be numbers instead of tuples.

```
    def getSeason(dt):
        season = None    
        for t, ranges in seasons.items():
            for start, end in ranges:
                if date(dt.year,start(0),start(1)) <= dt.date() <= date(dt.year,end(0),end(1)):
                    season = t
                    break
            if season is not None:
                break
        return season
```

Comment: Dates are pretty meaningless without years. You should store the years as well.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, OP is just checking if a given date is within a season (Fall, spring, etc).  No year needed for that.

If OP does include the year, then using datetime.date would be a good idea, though.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I know how to handle dates. In my case I need (month,day) pairs without years. Wel, I know the task that I should solve...

Comment: @Dinosaurius:  If your data does not need years it probably should not overlap.  `'S3'` ends on a `(9, 30)`.  `'S2'` starts on a `(9, 1)`.  Unless it's valid to place something in two seasons at the same time your criteria is invalid.  If you are depending on iteration order to privilege one season over another using a Python dictionary will not help you because iteration order need not follow definition order.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: No overlappings

Comment: @Dinosaurius:  Your data says otherwise.  That's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues, i see with your code -

1. You seem to be assuming you have a tuple of tuple of tuples, but you actually have a tuple of tupe, because when you try to make a tuple of one element, you need to follow the element by a `,` , otherwise python will interpret it as brackets used for grouping. Example -

   ```
   a = ((1,2),)
   ```

   In simple case,

   ```
   a = (1,)
   ```
2. Secondly, when accessing a tuple value, you should use `start[0]` , not `start(0)` , as the latter is trying to call it as a function, with `0` as parameter.
3. Your logic does not consider the case where the season start is in one year, whereas the season end is in the next year.

So seasons would look like -

```
seasons = {
    'S1': (
        ((1, 10),(5, 31)),
    ),
    'S2': (
        ((9, 1),(1, 9)),
    ),
    'S3': (
        ((6, 1),(9, 30)),
    )
}
```

A small change to your original `getSeason()` function, to make your case work -

```
def getSeason(dt):
    season = None    
    for t, ranges in seasons.items():
        for start, end in ranges:
            if start[0] <= end[0] or (start[0] == end[0] and start[1] <= end[1]):
                if date(dt.year,start[0],start[1]) <= dt.date() <= date(dt.year,end[0],end[1]):
                    season = t
                    break
            else:
                if (date(dt.year,start[0],start[1]) <= dt.date() <= date(dt.year+1,end[0],end[1])) or (date(dt.year-1,start[0],start[1]) <= dt.date() <= date(dt.year,end[0],end[1])):
                    season = t
                    break
        if season is not None:
            break
    return season
```

The above would work, but you don't really need a tuple of tuple of tuples for your use case, you can change the logic in your `getSeasons()` function to use a tuple of tuple .

Answer (score -1):

The main problem is that you're unpacking the tuple thus getting an `int` into `start` and `end`. if you remove the nested loop your code will work as you expect:

```
from datetime import datetime

seasons = {
    'S1': (
        (1, 10), (5, 31),
    ),
    'S2': (
        (9, 1), (1, 9),
    ),
    'S3': (
        (6, 1), (9, 30),
    )
}


def getSeason(dt):
    for t, (start, end) in seasons.iteritems():
        if start[0] < end[0] and datetime(dt.year, start[0], start[1]) <= dt <= datetime(dt.year, end[0], end[1]):
            return t

        elif (start[0] > end[0] and
                  (datetime(dt.year, start[0], start[1]) <= dt <= datetime(dt.year + 1, end[0], end[1]) or
                   datetime(dt.year - 1, start[0], start[1]) <= dt <= datetime(dt.year, end[0], end[1]))):
            return t

        else:
            continue

    return None
```

Comment: Bugs: `getSeason(datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 31))` and `getSeason(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1))` each return `None`.  Ambiguity: `getSeason(datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 1))` returns `'S3'` when it very well could return `'S2'`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski the bug is in the dictionary definitions of seasons as there are overlapping values and not all days of the year are covered. I added a more correct dict to avoid the original input problems.

Comment: It is legitimate that a season could span a year boundary.  I don't think should be defined away.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski you're correct about the first two however there is nothing to do about the ambiguity as it is inherent in the definition of his seasons (I think its a typo and S2 starts at Oct 1st and not Sep 1st).

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
from datetime import date

seasons = {
    'S1': (
        ((1, 10),(5, 31))
    ),
    'S2': (
        ((9, 1),(1, 9))
    ),
    'S3': (
        ((6, 1),(9, 30))
    )
}

def getSeason(dt):
    for sname, duration in seasons.items():
        start, end = duration
        start_date = date(dt.year, start[0], start[1])
        end_date = date(dt.year, end[0], end[1])
        if dt < start_date:
            start_date = date(start_date.year - 1, start_date.month, start_date.day)
            end_date = date(end_date.year - 1, end_date.month, end_date.day)
        if end_date < start_date:
            end_date = date(end_date.year+1, end_date.month, end_date.day)
        if start_date <= dt <= end_date:
            return sname
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = getSeason(date(1921, 5, 24))
    print s
```

Comment: Bugs: `getSeason(date(1921, 12, 31))` and
 `getSeason(date(1921, 1, 1))` each return `None`.

Comment: You are correct of course, I may have misinterpreted the question to be about iteration, not about the date algorithm.